# Windows Service running in multiple instances - best practice?

Tags: windows-services

I have a project where a number of 'environments' are running simultaniously: Local development environment (VS), Dev, Test and Prod.

We now wish to expand the program suite with a 'server application' to process background assignments as calculations and mail sending.

I'm trying to find best practice for this situation.

I'm thinking that it should be a windows service.

As a result, I need to have three copies of the service running (Dev, Test and Prod) and preferable on the single server assigned as our application server. I'm thinking I can copy relevant exe to separate directories and 'somehow' instruct each service which environment it is supposed to connect to.

It's important to notice that the three services would not nessesarily be running the same release of the code.

What is the best practice for doing this?

Any input appreciated!

Anders, Denmark

Comment: Define "background assignments", "calculations" and "mail sending".  I understand you're using Windows, probably talking about some kind of Windows Service, and after that have no idea what you're talking about. :)

Answer (score 2):

Definitely sounds like Windows Services would be the right call. These services would be daemons, running independently from each other.

I recommend against creating 3 executables. Stick with just one as it is easier for deployment.
Have your exe take a command line parameter telling it which environment it should run, and fire off the appropriate part of the code.

Its then pretty easy to start, stop and query your services.

Let me know your thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

Use an application config file for each installed instance of the service executable so you can set the environment to run against.